# Python. Использование супер конструктора. Как сделать так, чтобы при создании экземпляра класса требовалось ввести атрибуты дочернего и род. класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование

Имеется два класса (дочерний и родительский). В обоих определены конструкторы.

Как написать конструктор дочернего класса, чтобы при создании его экземпляра требовалось вводить как атрибуты дочернего, так и родительского? И возможно ли это вообще?

```
class Transport:
    def __init__(self, weight, fuelType, bodyColor, maxSpeed, engineCapacity, mileage, acelerationFrom0To100, enginePower):
        self.weight = weight
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.bodyColor = bodyColor
        self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
        self.engineCapacity = engineCapacity
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.acelerationFrom0To100 = acelerationFrom0To100
        self.enginePower = enginePower
 
class PassengerCar(Transport):    
    def __init__(self, countOfPassengerSeats, trunkVolume, interiorColor):
        Transport().__init__() # это не помогает....
        self.countOfPassengerSeats = countOfPassengerSeats
        self.trunkVolume = trunkVolume
        self.interiorColor = interiorColor
```

Comment: `Transport().__init__(...)`, где `...` - аргументы инициализатора `Transport` без `self`? Может использовать `*args` в конце `PassengerCar` и передавать его в `Transport`?

Comment: дело в том, что перепробовал уже разные варианты, и с self, и с передачей всех аргументов реакции 0 при создании экземпляра запрашивает только атрибуты дочернего класса, а родительского игнорирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуйте доступ к родительскому классу через super, а не через имя этого класса. Это, как минимум, удобнее. В примере ниже все значения атрибутов одноименны их названиям.

```
# Date: October 26th, 2020.
class Transport:
    def __init__(self, weight, fuelType, bodyColor, maxSpeed,
                    engineCapacity, mileage, acelerationFrom0To100,
                    enginePower):
        self.weight = weight
        self.fuelType = fuelType
        self.bodyColor = bodyColor
        self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
        self.engineCapacity = engineCapacity
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.acelerationFrom0To100 = acelerationFrom0To100
        self.enginePower = enginePower

class PassengerCar(Transport):
    def __init__(self, countOfPassengerSeats, trunkVolume,
                    interiorColor, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.countOfPassengerSeats = countOfPassengerSeats
        self.trunkVolume = trunkVolume
        self.interiorColor = interiorColor

attributes=(
    "countOfPassengerSeats", "trunkVolume", "interiorColor",
    "weight", "fuelType", "bodyColor", "maxSpeed", "engineCapacity",
    "mileage", "acelerationFrom0To100", "enginePower")
obj=PassengerCar(*attributes)

for attribute in dir(obj):
    if attribute in attributes:
        print(f"<attribute '{attribute}': '{getattr(obj, attribute)}'>")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как написать конструктор дочернего класса, чтобы при создании его
> экземпляра требовалось вводить как атрибуты дочернего, так и
> родительского?

Принимать в методе `__init__` дочернего класса аргументы для родительского класса. Тогда при создании экземпляра дочернего класса нужно будет обеспечить аргументы для обоих методов `__init__` - родительского и дочернего.

```
class PassengerCar(Transport):
    def __init__(self, 
                    # Аргументы родительского класса
                    weight, fuelType, bodyColor,
                    maxSpeed, engineCapacity, mileage,
                    acelerationFrom0To100, enginePower,
                    # Аргументы дочернего класса
                    countOfPassengerSeats, trunkVolume, interiorColor):
        # Передаём родительскому классу его аргументы
        super().__init__(weight, fuelType, и т. д.)
```

**Пример:**

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c): 
        self.a = a
        self.b = b 
        self.c = c 
            
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e): 
        #  Вызываем родительский "__init__" и передаём ему его аргументы        
        super().__init__(a, b, c)
        self.d = d 
        self.e = e
#  При создании объекта передаём аргументы для двух методов "__init__":
#  первые три для родительского,
#  последние два для дочернего
obj = Child(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

from pprint import pprint
#  Атрибуты объекта хранятся в словаре __dict__, проверяем его содержимое
pprint(obj.__dict__, width=20)
```

Начиная с **Python 3.7** можно автоматизировать создание атрибутов с помощью `dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent:
  a: int
  b: int
  c: int
            
@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
  d: int
  e: int

obj = Child(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(obj.__dict__, width=20)
```